# Prove that group of $2$-nd roots of unity form a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am not sure if I could explain the problem in the description but here it is:

Let $C_n$ be group of all n-th roots of unity. Let $G=\{z\in C | z^2 \in C_n \}$.Check that $G$ is a group. Which group is this.

I don't know much about complex numbers but this is what I did.

Let $a,b\in G$. As $a^2=1$(is this what the definition of the group says?), $a=a^{-1}$, same with $b$. Obviously $(ab)^2=1$, as $ab=ba$.

Is this correct? Did I understand the definition of $G$ correctly?

Comment: Yeah this is it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $x\in C_n$ then $x^n=1$ thus if $z^2\in C_n$ then $(z^2)^n=z^{2n}=e$ conversly if $z^{2n}=e$ then $z^2\in C_n$.

Thus, $G=\{z\in C|z^{2n}=e\}$ but that means that $G=C_{2n}$ and if you know trhat $C_n$ is a group for all $n$ then $G$ must be a group !

Comment: Is my version wrong? Your version is better looking and professional way but can my professor deduct points for mine?

Comment: @khajvah: The missing point in your argument is that if $a\in G$, $a^2$ need not be equal to $1$ but you can say $a^{2n}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$C_m = \{\omega\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ \omega^m = 1\}$$

Thus
$$z\in G     \ \overset{\text{def of G}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\ 
z^2\in C_n   \ \overset{\text{def of $C_n$}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\ 
\left(z^2\right)^n = 1 \ \Longleftrightarrow\ 
z^{2n} = 1 \ \Longleftrightarrow\ z\in C_{2n}$$

Then $G=C_{2n}$, which is a group.